# How to run selected scenario only based on tags in cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I have scenarios as below in my feature file:

```
@tag1
Scenario1

@tag2 @tag1
Scenario2

@tag3 @tag1
Scenario3
```

So I want to execute Scenario1 having only @tag1 but do not want to execute scenario2 and scenario3. How to do that.

I have tried below option:

```
-Dcucumber.options='--tags "((@tag1) and (not @tag2 or not @tag3)"'
```

But it is executing all 3 scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Cucumber v6 you can no longer use `cucumber.options` with a command line like string. Instead you'll have to use individual properties.

```sh
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="(@cucumber or @gherkin) and not @salad"
```

From: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options